# Phase differences approximation

Tags: physics, approximation

I'm sitting and trying to solve the equation of the phase difference given by:

$\Delta \phi = k (\sqrt{a^2+d^2} -d ) \approx \frac{ka^2}{2d}$

Where $a$ is the size of an aperture and $b$ is the distance the point at the aperture's center as shown in the figure below.

[Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XYg7.png)

I'm not a math expert here, so I wondering if anyone can explain the approximation that has been done above here.

**Reference:**

Applications of Classical Physics by Roger D. Blandford and Kip S. Thorne - Chapter 8 - Diffraction

Answer (score 0):

$$k\sqrt{a^2 +d^2} -kd = d k\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{d^2}} -1 \right)$$

Assuming $\frac {a^2}{d^2}$ is small, you can binomially approximate (for small $x$, $\sqrt {1+x} \approx 1+\frac 12 x$):

$$\approx dk \left( (1+\frac{a^2}{2d^2}) -1 \right)\\ =\frac{ka^2}{2d}$$

Comment: I see! The problem is that $k$ which is a wave number can be any integer and the assumption that $d \approx 0 $ is invalid, so the last equation doesn't hold. Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @KantheeKosolyuthasarn What about $a$? Can you assume anything?

Comment: $a$ is the length of an aperture/opening which is always greater than 0. In some cases, $a$ can approximate to be much lesser than $d$.

Comment: @KantheeKosolyuthasarn Alright, so the binomial approximation works in those cases. It’s hard to say how the author neglected the $d(k-1)$ term.

Comment: Ah, I'm so sorry, there was a typo. It should be $\Delta \phi = k (\sqrt{a^2+d^2} -d) \approx \frac{ka^2}{2d}$ . You were right, the binomial theorem works just fine here. Thank you again.

Comment: @KantheeKosolyuthasarn I was expecting something like that. You’re welcome.